# Is there an elegant way to chain join() after a foreach()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, coding-style

I am trying to write something like this:

```
DOMElement
 .innerHTML
 .toLowerCase()
 .split(' ')
 .forEach(function(word) {
   return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
 })
 .join(' ')
```

Since `join` needs to receive an `array`, is there an elegant way to provide it one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could replace [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
.map(function(word) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
})
```